# Rscript execution error: No such file or directory

Tags: r, rscript

The binary of Rscript is available but when I try to use it I get:

```
Rscript helloworld.r

Rscript execution error: No such file or directory
```

If I just do Rscript, it brings the help/usage for it through.

R CMD BATCH is working fine.

I tried adding shebang lines in the R code at the start but it didn't work.

*#!/sys_apps_01/R/R-3.2.0/bin/R*

*#!/sys_apps_01/R/R-3.2.0/bin/Rscript*

Comment: What is your operating system and what does `which Rscript` return?

Comment: OS is RedHat 6 and Rscript returns the usage of Rscript (Usage: /path/to/Rscript [--options] [-e expr [-e expr2 ...] | file] [args])

Comment: bash-4.1$ which Rscript
/sys_apps_01/R/R-3.2.0/bin/Rscript

Answer (score 3):

As in your case, this was caused by me moving R (in order to try to use it in an AWS lambda function).

I resorted to doing the equivalent call on R itself:

```
./R --slave --no-restore --file=TheScript.R
```

Comment: This is easiest b/c it doesn't require monkeying with homebrew's symlinks.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely this was installed to (configured for) another directory and then moved **after** installation. Afterwards Rscript won't be able to find the (hardcoded?) R binary. I just had the same problem, which could be solved by reinstalling R.

Andreas

Comment: Yes, R was installed and was moved afterwards. How can I use R and RScript from this custom location?

Answer (score 0):

I preface this solution issuing a caution to do this at one's own risk. However I encountered the same issue and had the following solution:

Say you've run `make && make install` which has installed R to `/path/to/install/loc`. Once you've moved this to `path/to/new/loc`, R/Rscript will then complain it can't find the right file/directory.

Editing the `R` and `Rscript` executables in `path/to/new/loc/bin`, you can change any reference to `/path/to/old/loc` to `/path/to/new/loc`. This has worked for me and haven't encountered any further issues

As has been previously mentioned, it's definitely preferable to install R to the required location either through `prefix=...` in the `configure` script, or by using the `rhome=...` argument following `make install`

Comment: Are you sure this is working I see Rscript being $ file /opt/third/R/4.0.0/bin/Rscript 
/opt/third/R/4.0.0/bin/Rscript: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs) how do you "change reference" ?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. What happened in my case was that, R was first installed at `/usr/lib/R` with deb packages, then I moved the dir to `/opt/R` and defined `R_HOME` to the new dir, hoping R will adapt to it automatically, but turns out there are hardcoded paths of `/usr/lib/R` in `bin/R`. Unless I update the paths, simply moving R to another location will break the installation.