# File not found when using Rscript command

Tags: r, linux

I am trying to run a R script on Linux using Rscript command. However, it gives me an error stating that no such file or directory.

[image]

Weirdly, when I use command "less" on that R script, it works and displays the script on the screen.
Can anyone explaining this to me ?

Comment: If you need help with code you should show the code that's causing the problem with a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Right now we have no idea exactly what you are running so it's impossible to say what's going on.

Comment: Hi, I just want to execute the R script on Linux. When I type Rscript file.R. It says that there is no such file. I have already checked files available in the folder using "ls", and the file is actually there. I also tried to type less file.R, and it has no problem displaying the code on the screen. It means that for other commands, they detect the file in the folder

Comment: What exactly are you typing on the command like to try to run the script? Is the error an OS error or an R error? It would be helpful to be more clear about exactly what you are typing/seeing.

Comment: Hi, I just edited my post with the command that I used

Comment: The Rscript worked before the `ssmuse-sh` line. What does that line do on your system. Is the `which Rscript` different before and after? Seems like it points to a botched R install after you run that line.

Comment: Since I don't have permission to install any R library on the system. I only can use the available R library on the system. ssmuse-sh directs me to that library. The which Rscript is indeed different before and after

Comment: Then I would contact your systems administrator for help. Sounds like the file was not installed correctly.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39832110/rscript-execution-error-no-such-file-or-directory